# Unwanted carriage returns added when unmarshalling from ByteStreamArray

Tags: java, unmarshalling, carriage-return

I have the following code:

```
String resultXml = queryForXml(input);
Unmarshaller u = readDocument.createUnmarshaller();
            JAXBElement<ReadDocumentByKeyReplyType> root = (JAXBElement<ReadDocumentByKeyReplyType>) u.unmarshal(new ByteArrayInputStream(resultXml.getBytes()));
```

One of the ReadDocumentByKeyReplyType objects stores a String, but this string is basically an HTML page. The end tag of the HTML elements creates a natural line break, which the unmarshaller then adds a carriage return to in the unmarshalling process. This of course messes up the HTML.

```
<style type=\"text/css\">\n        .active-header-link {\n            background-color: #00604A;\n        }\n\n
```

I can call the replaceAll("\n", "") on the String once it is unmarshalled, but these HTML documents have jpeg images embedded as base64. Invariably one of these encodings will have a '\n' in it, and the replaceAll call will corrupt the jpeg. Is there a way to tell the unmarshaller to not add carriage returns?

Comment: This is unclear.  What is `readDocument`?  Please show a [mcve].  Also _"one of these encodings will have a '\n' in it"_ -- that shouldn't be the case, you are going to have to explicitly show what you mean, with actual data samples.  Also, why do you think the unmarshaller is the one inserting the `\n` characters?

Comment: Also, an unmarshaller returns a content tree, it has no reason to be adding `\n` at the ends of tags.  In fact, the single example you give looks like a nicely hand indented CSS declaration, which was probably that way in the input.